# Merging arrays slices in Python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

So I have a string that looks like this:

```
data="ABCABDABDABBCBABABDBCABBDBACBBCDB"
```

And I am taking random 10 character slices out of it:

```
start=int(random.random()*100)
end = start+10
slice = data[start:start+10]
```

But what I am trying to do now is count the number of 'gaps' or 'holes' that were not sliced out at all.

```
slices_indices = []
for i in xrange(0,100):
    start=int(random.random()*100)
    end= 10
    slice = data[start:end]
    ...
    slices_indices.append([start,end])
```

For instance, after running this a couple times. I covered this amount:

**ABCAB** DABD **ABBCBABABDB** C **ABBDBACBBCDB**

But left two 'gaps' of slices. Is there a 'Pythonic' way to find the number of these gaps? So basically I am looking for a function that `count_gaps` given the slice indices.

For example above,

```
count_gaps(slices_indices)
```

would give me two

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is not well defined. Imagine you can identify two pieces of the big list and there is a string `BABAB` in the middle. Then you've got a slice `AB`, which can't be placed uniquely and the decision obviously changes the output number.

Comment: I have the slice indices however (not just the slice itself), this could be done with for loops.

Comment: I would do this in two steps: 1. Find all indices that aren't covered by any of the ranges you've sliced out; then 2. Group consecutive indices and count the groups.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a cool one-liner or something Pythonic `count_gaps(slice_indices)`. But I guess I'll need to do it the old fashion way

Comment: Yes, you will have to write `count_gaps`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several, although all involve a bit of messing about

You could compare the removed strings against the original, and work out which characters you didn't hit.

That's a very roundabout way of doing it, though, and won't work properly if you ever have the same 10 characters in the string twice. eg 1234123 or something.

A better solution would be to store the values of i you use, then step back through the data string comparing the current position to the values of i you used (plus 10). If it doesn't match, job done.

eg (pseudo code)

```
# Make an array the same length as the string
charsUsed = array(data.length)

# Do whatever
for i in xrange(0,100)
    someStuffYouWereDoingBefore()

    # Store our "used chars" in the array
    for(char = i; char < i+10; char++)
        if(char <= data.length) # Don't go out of bounds on the array!
            charsUsed[i] = true
```

Then to see which chars weren't used, just walk through charsUsed array and count whatever it is you want to count (consecutive gaps etc)

Edit in response to updated question:
I'd still use the above method to make a "which chars were used" array. Your count_gaps() function then just needs to walk through the array to "find" the gaps

eg (pseudo...something. This isn't even vaguely Python. Hopefully you get the idea though)
The idea is essentially to see if the current position is false (ie not used) and the last position is true (used) meaning it's the start of a "new" gap. If both are false, we're in the middle of a gap, and if both are true, we're in the middle of a "used" string

```
function find_gaps(array charsUsed)
{
    # Count the gaps
    numGaps = 0
    # What did we look at last (to see if it's the start of a gap)
    # Assume it's true if you want to count "gaps" at the start of the string, assume it's false if you don't.
    lastPositionUsed = true

    for(i = 0; i < charsUsed.length; i++)
    {
        if(charsUsed[i] = false && lastPositionUsed = true)
        {
            numGaps++
        }
        lastPositionUsed = charsUsed[i]
    }

    return numGaps
}
```

The other option would be to step through the charsUsed array again and "group" consecutive values into a smaller away, then count the value you want... essentially the same thing but with a different approach. With this example I just ignore group I don't want and the "rest" of the group I do, counting only the boundaries between the group we don't want, and the group we do.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I just updated the question. Maybe it would give further insight

Comment: Updated the answer to include a more comprehensive description of one possible approach to the count_gaps method. There are several other ways you can do it

Comment: Thanks again Jon. That was the way I would have done it. I was also hoping that this entire function could be done in one line using some special Python technique - but guess not!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a messy task, but I think sets are the way to go. I hope my code below is self-explanatory, but if there are parts you don't understand please let me know.

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Count gaps.

    Find and count the sections in a sequence that weren't touched by random slicing
    From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060688/merging-arrays-slices-in-python
    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.09.27
'''

import random
from string import ascii_lowercase


def main():
    def rand_slice():
        start = random.randint(0, len(data) - slice_width) 
        return start, start + slice_width

    #The data to slice
    data = 5 * ascii_lowercase
    print 'Data:\n%s\nLength : %d\n' % (data, len(data))

    random.seed(42)

    #A set to capture slice ranges
    slices = set()    
    slice_width = 10    
    num_slices = 10
    print 'Extracting %d slices from data' % num_slices
    for i in xrange(num_slices):
        start, end = rand_slice()
        slices |= set(xrange(start, end))
        data_slice = data[start:end].upper()
        print '\n%2d, %2d : %s' % (start, end, data_slice)
        data = data[:start] + data_slice + data[end:]
        print data
        #print sorted(slices)

    print '\nSlices:\n%s\n' % sorted(slices)

    print '\nSearching for gaps missed by slicing'
    unsliced = sorted(tuple(set(xrange(len(data))) - slices))
    print 'Unsliced:\n%s\n' % (unsliced,)

    gaps = []    
    if unsliced:
        last = start = unsliced[0]
        for i in unsliced[1:]:
            if i > last + 1:
                t = (start, last + 1)
                gaps.append(t)
                print t
                start = i
            last = i
        t = (start, last + 1)
        gaps.append(t)
        print t

    print '\nGaps:\n%s\nCount: %d' % (gaps, len(gaps))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some kind of bitmap. For example, Extending your code:

```
data="ABCABDABDABBCBABABDBCABBDBACBBCDB"

slices_indices = [0]*len(data)
for i in xrange(0,100):
    start=int(random.random()*len(data))
    end=start + 10
    slice = data[start:end]
    slices_indices[start:end] = [1] * len(slice)
```

I've used a `list` here, but you could use any other appropriate data structure, probably something more compact, if your data is rather big.

So, we've initialized the bitmap with zeros, and marked with ones the selected chunks of data. Now we can use something from `itertools`, for example:

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby(slices_indices)
```

`groupby` returns an iterator where each element is a tuple `(element, iterator)`. To just count gaps you can do something simple, like:

```
gaps = len([x for x in groups if x[0] == 0])
```

Comment: Note that the example assumes variable sized slices (that's why `[1] * len(slice)`